# Artisan make:controller Doesn't work and no error

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I'm using Laravel 5.3.0 and it's running on a local server with Manjaro. I access the project folder trough ssh and I'm also using artisan trough SSH.

Everything runs fine, I run the server trough terminal:

```
php artisan serve --host 192.168.0.10 --port 80
```

And can acess the project trough browser.

But when I run this command:

```
php artisan make:controller ContatoController
```

or

```
artisan make:controller ContatoController
```

Nothing happens, it get's stuck, no message error after minutes. No controller is created.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: only make:controller is not working or any other php artisan command is also not working ?

Comment: Are you in the right directory when you execute the command? When i'm creating a controller i first have to browse into my laravel project directory and run the command from there.

Comment: @DhavalChheda, php artisan env and other command's are running. Funny fact: I installed locally to test and the command also doesn't runs.

Comment: @Mr.Greenwoodz I'm inside laravel project directory.

Comment: Guys, that was silly.

What happens is that first you create controller and after that you run server?!

I'm running a course and in this course they tell you to run server and than run the make:controller .

I'm confuse. Is that correct?

Comment: Your server has to be running in order to execute the command (i think!). Atleast that sounds kinda logical to me. I followed the laracasts tutorial on https://laracasts.com/. Everything is explained really good there. Perhaps you could give that a try?

Comment: your server has to be running otherwise how will a PHP script run?

Comment: @DhavalChheda yes, but server was running! I first run the server and in the same terminal I run the make:controller command. However, it was the wrong way. I can run the server in one terminal and use the commands in another one. Than it works.

Comment: @Mr.Greenwoodz it was running off course. If is not running, it throws an error, it wasen't the case but is solved.

Comment: Ah yes, so the problem was you were running the server but to execute the command you first stopped the server. To eliminate this problem you could do the following: change your xampp httpd.conf file and allow virtual hosts. Then add an address to your hosts file. Then all you have to do is add a virtual host in your httpd-vhosts.conf. After this, when you run apache you don't have to use your terminal again to run the server;) This is what i do running a local Laravel project and it's working great:)

Comment: @Mr.Greenwoodz thank's for your help. Actually, I was not stopping the server, he kept running, in fact, I was making other tests using Google Chrome, so it was fine. I feel so dumb right now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what happened:

I was running artisan server and after that (on the same terminal) I was running the make:controller command.

The solution was:
1- Open linux terminal, run artisan server;
2- Open another terminal (or split window if you'r using Terminator) and use all commands you want.